# Regex to match a string if not followed by another string

Tags: regex, mariadb, mediawiki, pcre

In [**Mediawiki via Replace extension**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) (MariaDB 10.6) I want to match the string `<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A</span>` and delete it, as long as there is no `<span class="bld">` further down that line. Here is an example of text where it should not be matched:

```
<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A</span> [[lay bare at the side]], [[expose]], τι τῆς πλευρᾶς <span class="bibl">Arr. <span class="title">Tact.</span>40.5</span>, cf. <span class="bibl">D.C.49.6</span> (Pass.). </span><span class="sense"><span class="bld">2</span> metaph., [[lay bare]], [[disclose]], τὸν πάντα λόγον <span class="bibl">Hdt.1.126</span>, cf. <span class="bibl">8.19</span>, <span class="bibl">9.44</span>; τὸ βούλευμα <span class="bibl">Conon 50</span>:—Pass., <b class="b3">παρεγυμνώθη διότι</b>… <span class="bibl">Plb.1.80.9</span>.</span>
```

So far I tried `(<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A<\/span>) ((?!<span class="bld">).*)` (and replacing with nothing) but it matches instances that do contain the unwanted string.

Comment: Try `<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A</span>(?s)(?!.*<span class="bld">)`

Comment: Thanks! I had to escape the slash to make it work `<\/span>`

Comment: In MariaDB? No need to escape it, you do not use regex literals in the code. [Look here](https://regex101.com/r/Bjf8WJ/1), no need to escape `/` anywhere. `/` is not any special regex metacharacter, it only needs to be escaped in patterns that are defined with regex literals where regex delimiter char is a slash.

Comment: Well, not directly in MariaDB, via Mediawiki Replace Text extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text (this is the only way it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A<\/span>(?s)(?!.*<span class="bld">)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bjf8WJ/2). *Details*:

- `<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A<\/span>` - a literal `<span class="sense"><span class="bld">A</span>` string
- `(?s)` - `s` flag that makes `.` match across lines
- `(?!.*<span class="bld">)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
  - `<span class="bld">` - a literal string.